# SPSS statistics vs modeler

Tags: spss

I have a problem statement like to predict the loan defaulter with the given 5 to 10 years data. I was told that we could use SPSS, but I'm new to this. Also, I see that there is Statistics and Modeler. Are they two different tools? which one should I explore for my problem? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

They are different tools from the same company. Modeler it's more intuitive but statistics it's a great software as well. Both could do predictions as you need.
You can try time series models or multiple regression to do that. Take a look on the officials manuals from IBM also to help in your decision.